# block access of a website from other computers using same ip

Tags: linux, .htaccess, security, ip

I need to make a website secure so that only me and 2 other collegues in the office can access it. For that the first step i did is to block the access of all other ips except the office ip via creating an .htaccess file as follows

```
 # ALLOW USER BY IP
<Limit GET POST>
 order deny,allow
 deny from all
 allow from 2.59.42.32
</Limit>

# PREVENT VIEWING OF .HTACCESS
<Files .htaccess>
 order allow,deny
 deny from all
</Files>
```

Now there are 30 other computers + other phone devices which has all the same ip. How can i block all the 27 computers and all devices to access this website? any idea?

Note: The website has a password for signing in. but I need to make it extra secure so that the password is not misused by the employees who have them. There is a possibility that the employees (to whom access is granted) can share it with other collegues.

Possible solutions:

1. I get an email of other computer names if they sign in?
2. I get a notification via email that more than 3 members are online?

Comment: Can't you just give your colleagues a password? It'd be way more secure than any IP or MAC whitelisting hack.

Comment: yes. it has a password for signing in. but I need to make it extra secure so that the password is not misused by the employees who have them. There is a possibility that the employees (to whom access is granted) can share it with other collegues

Comment: This link might be useful. You can block all the ip addresses in your network and allow only ips of your and your friends' computer. http://www.htaccess-guide.com/deny-visitors-by-ip-address/

Answer (score 0):

You can set up SSL on the web server and authenticate to it using a certificate that only exists on that particular machine.

You can see this [link](http://monduke.com/2006/06/04/the-fifteen-minute-guide-to-mutual-authentication/)

Comment: the link doesnt open in UAE. its restricted. can u suggest some other link plz